# How to make a cylindric wrapping go all arround

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, text-wrap

I´m using After Effects and the cylindric wrapping tool for Text. The Text has the right size and everything, the only problem is, that the wrapping won´t close all the way. There is always a gap left. [image: gap between both ends]
How do I get rid of the gap? (Emphasizing the Text won´t do the trick)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question, you need to wrap the text (which I didn't see) around the pillar with an animation of your choice.

I did a sample which I think should solve the problem, by creating New Composition, and inside that composition after placing your BG and other layers, you have to think of the pillar in a way that could walk side by side with your wrapping Idea.

Follow my steps to get the same results as mine:

01 - When you draw the pillar, try to draw a perfect tall rectangle and apply (Warp) Effect.

02 - Edit the (Wrap Style) to be "Arc Lower".

03 - Lower the third option value (Bend) to be something around 84 or around.

[image: Draw a perfect tall Rectangle]
[image]

04 - After applying the effect it will give you something like this.

[image: The rectangle after adding wrap effect and changing some values]

05 - Create your text layer or animation solid layer and pre-compose it.
 -- I created shapes animation from left to right.

[image: Animated Shapes in a separated composition]
[image: Layers Order after adding the text comp]

06 - apply (CC Cylinder) effect and change the radius to 69%.
   -apply (Warp) effect and do the same thing that you did with the pillar shape layer or just copy the wrap effec from the pillar and then paste it under CC Cylindar effect.

That should give you something like this:

[image: After applying the effects on the text layer comp]

07 - Turn on the collapse transformations switch on the Text Layer.

[image: Turning on Collapse Transformations Switch On Text Layer]

08 - Control Your Animation From inside the Text Comp or from outside it, or both.

That's it!

This is my result.

[image: Final Animation]

Hope that answers the question

Ahmad Murad